# WebStorm Smarty highlighting

Tags: ide, smarty, webstorm

Is there an way to make WebStorm highlight Smarty templates? Either through plugin or some other means?

Also note, I need this for WebStorm, not PhpStorm or some other version; I don't need autocomplete or anything else -- just highlights.

Files have `.tpl` extension and so far I'm treating them as HTML files and I am looking for options to increase code readability with coloring.

---

I have tried following based on the comments:
[image: bundle window]
[image: file type window]

However, resulting .tpl file still looks like
[image: result]

Comment: The only possible option for WebStorm is via TextMate bundles (if you will find one, of course, but considering how old Smarty is it should not be an issue) -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/TextMate+Bundles+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Erm, why would this get -1?

Also, the link provided is for PhpStorm, but I will see if it is same/possible for WebStorm

Comment: 1) No idea. But looks like somebody does not like what you were asking 2) Because that manual was created by PhpStorm people (as it was originally targeted users who wanted python/ruby syntax coloring). But it is a separate plugin so will work in any supported IDE.

Comment: I've tried this solution, however it did not work. I imported smarty via TextMate bundles, assigned *.tpl wildcard to types supported by textmate bundles and result was plain text. No highlighting what so ever.

Comment: Maybe you can add a php plugins?